# What's the correct way to make an Index (Table of contents) in HTML

Tags: html, specifications

You can use `<h1>` to `<h6>` to structure your text. But:

What's the correct / best way, to make a separate Index (Table of Contents) to the text? (on the same page as the text)

Usually, I would just make a `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` list, listing every title from every `<h1>` ... `<h6>`, but that probably wouldnt be a good solution, right? I'm especially talking about external readers (for blind people, for example, or maybe other programs) or even Search engines that read the HTML - they basically would see every title twice then...

I'm just wondering, if there is a predefined / best practice way to do that.

Comment: First of all, `<ol>` as it should be an ordered list. I'd go with a simple ordered list. No headlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table of contents and index are two different things. You probably mean the former.

It matters very little which markup you use, as long as you use normal links with descriptive link text (normally echoing the headings). You normally don’t want any browser-generated bullets or numbers, but the simplest choice is to use `ul` with `list-style-type: none`, using nested `ul` elements for different levels of headings.

A table of content means duplication, of course, and assistive software might be capable of constructing a table of contents from the heading elements. Still, for most purposes, an explicit table of content at the start is good usability and accessibility for any longish page. It lets the reader (seeing or blind) go through the headings first and then choose the jump somewhere or read sequentially.